# Set font size equal between UIButtons and adjustable according to their width

Tags: ios

I'm using auto-layout (programmatically) and I'm facing a problem.

I have three buttons aligned side-by-side, and I'm trying to adapt their `titleLabel`'s font size so they fit their width.

The thing is, I'd also like these three buttons to have the same font size, so everything is consistent.

But if I use this property :

```
self.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Then, only one of the buttons adapts its font size.

Is it possible to set a constraint on the font size, or do you guys have an other idea?

Comment: set their widths to equal each other and enable adjusting font size to all of them.

Comment: Hm, but if one of the titles is "Hey tap here, please" and an other one is "Tap", then their width should't be equal

Comment: unfortunately you cant do it with autolayout, you have to calculate the minimum font size yourself.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, I was hoping for some marvellous hidden method :-). Thank you !